# polynomial modulus question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to solve $x^2 + x ≡ 44 \mod 56$. For part A and B I had to use trial and error to find the solutions to $x^2 + x ≡44 \mod 8$ and $x^2 + x ≡44 \mod7$.

For $x^2 + x ≡44 \mod 8 $ I found the solutions were $x≡ 3 \mod 8$ and $x ≡ 4 \mod 8$.

For  $x^2 + x ≡44 \mod 7$ I found the solutions were $x≡ 1 \mod 7$ and $x ≡ 5 \mod 7$.

I know these are correct since I double checked them. But the problem is I have to use the Chinese remainder theorem to solve solutions as a system meaning

$$ x ≡ 3 \mod  8 $$ 
$$ x ≡ 4 \mod  8 $$ 
$$ x ≡ 1 \mod 7 $$
$$ x ≡ 5 \mod 7 $$

but it won't work since the gcd's of the moduli are not pairwise disjoint. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yikes! Please check your typing and refer to the FAQ section for directions typing mathematics properly in this site with LaTeX.

Comment: You have $4$ **different** systems to solve (though much of the work can be recycled). Each system has shape $x\equiv a\pmod{8}$, $x\equiv b\pmod{7}$. The moduli *are* relatively prime.

Comment: what about gcd(8,8)? thats not prime.

Comment: $x\equiv 3$ or $4\pmod8$, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\:r\: $ is a root $\rm\:mod\ 8,\:$ and $\rm\:s\:$ is a root $\rm\:mod\ 7,\:$ then compute a root $\rm\:mod\ 56,\:$ using

$$\rm \begin{eqnarray} x\equiv r\,\ (mod\ 8)\\ \rm x\equiv s\,\ (mod\ 7)\end{eqnarray}\iff x \,\equiv\, 8s\!-\!7r\,\ (mod\ 56)$$

Comment: im stuck. i try to apply the chinese remainder theorem to the system of equations i got up there but it wont work.

Comment: @user60887 E.g. $\rm\:(r,s) = (4,5)\:$ so $\rm\:x\equiv 8s-7r\equiv 8\cdot 5-7\cdot 4 = 12\,\ (mod\ 56).\:$ Do the same for the other three combinations $\rm\:(4,1),\ (3,1),\ (3,5).\ \ $